# Does refreshing firebase/cicp auth token check 3rd party provider for revocation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity

Suppose a user signs in using a 3rd party provider, e.g., Google, Microsoft (AD), SAML, OIDC, etc. Typically, the refresh token is good for 2 weeks. If during that 2 week period, the user is deactivated on that provider (e.g., Google Workspace user suspended, or SSO user terminated in 3rd party database), does Firebase/CICP check with that 3rd party when refreshing an id token? Or does that only happen at the end of the 2 weeks, or when doing a fresh login?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#:%7E:text=Refresh%20tokens%20expire,also%20made%20available.):

> Refresh tokens expire only when one of the following occurs:
>
> - The user is deleted
> - The user is disabled
> - A major account change is detected for the user. This includes events like password or email address updates.
>
> The Firebase Admin SDK provides the ability to revoke
> refresh tokens for a specified user. **In addition, an API to check for**
> **ID token revocation is also made available.**

As I've highlighted above, Firebase provides an API checker that you can incorporate within your app to check if the refresh token is still valid from the 3rd party provider.

You may check [Detect ID token revocation in the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation_in_the_sdk) for more information.

Comment: Where do the docs discuss Firebase checking validity with the 3rd party provider?